# why do I receive an empty string when mapping Mono<Void> to Mono<String>?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am developing an API REST using Spring WebFlux, but I have problems when uploading files. They are stored but I don't get the expected return value.

This is what I do:

1. Receive a Flux<Part>
2. Cast Part to FilePart.
3. Save parts with transferTo() (this return a Mono<Void>)
4. Map the Mono<Void> to Mono<String>, using file name.
5. Return Flux<String> to client.

I expect file name to be returned, but client gets an empty string.

**Controller code**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/muscles/{id}/image")
public Flux<String> updateImage(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody Flux<Part> file) {
    log.info("REST request to update image to Muscle");
    return storageService.saveFiles(file);
}
```

**StorageService**

```
public Flux<String> saveFiles(Flux<Part> parts) {
    log.info("StorageService.saveFiles({})", parts);
    return
            parts
            .filter(p -> p instanceof FilePart)
            .cast(FilePart.class)
            .flatMap(file -> saveFile(file));
}

private Mono<String> saveFile(FilePart filePart) {
    log.info("StorageService.saveFile({})", filePart);
    String filename = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(filePart.filename() + new Date());
    Path target = rootLocation.resolve(filename);
    try {
        Files.deleteIfExists(target);
        File file = Files.createFile(target).toFile();

        return filePart.transferTo(file)
                .map(r -> filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note: instead of `.filter(p -> p instanceof FilePart)` you could also use `.filter(FilePart.class::isInstance)`

Comment: Could you add several `log` operators in your pipeline and share the logs here? Maybe one after the `cast` operator to know how many parts you're getting, then another one after the `flatMap` to know how many files were transferred.

Comment: Thanks for advices. I solved it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FilePart.transferTo()` returns `Mono<Void>`, which signals when the operation is done - this means the reactive `Publisher` will only publish an `onComplete`/`onError` signal and will never publish a value before that.

This means that the `map` operation was never executed, because it's only given elements published by the source.

You can return the name of the file and still chain reactive operators, like this:

```
return part.transferTo(file).thenReturn(part.filename());
```

It is forbidden to use the `block` operator within a reactive pipeline and it [even throws an exception at runtime as of Reactor 3.2](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/releases/tag/v3.2.0.M2).

Using `subscribe` as an alternative is not good either, because `subscribe` will decouple the transferring process from your request processing, making those happen in different execution sequences. This means that your server could be done processing the request and close the HTTP connection while the other part is still trying to read the file part to copy it on disk. This is likely to fail in subtle ways at runtime.

Comment: Hi, Brian, do you happen to know how to overcome issue when using transferTo and subscribe onComplete - processing request is done (i assume sending file over network is done), but file is still saving onto disk (because it uses mounted docker storage) ? thanks in advance

Comment: is it possible with transferTo to get signal when file is really fully saved when using mounted storage over network? i assume onComplete subscriber gets signal when file transfered over http but is still saving..

Comment: @Vovabackend_dev please ask this as a proper StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

FilePart.transferTo() returns Mono<Void> that is a constant empty. Then, map after that was never executed. I solved it by doing this:

```
private Mono<String> saveFile(FilePart filePart) {
    log.info("StorageService.saveFile({})", filePart);
    String filename = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(filePart.filename() + new Date());
    Path target = rootLocation.resolve(filename);
    try {
        Files.deleteIfExists(target);
        File file = Files.createFile(target).toFile();
        return filePart
                .transferTo(file)
                .doOnSuccess(data -> log.info("do something..."))
                .thenReturn(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: watch out, using `block` in this context is forbidden and is likely to throw an exception at runtime with the latest reactor version.

Comment: I just came to correct that. Adding more stuff I got the exception. Now I have this line:
filePart.transferTo(file).doOnSuccess(data -> log.info("do something...")).subscribe();

Comment: `subscribe` is not the right choice either - I've edited my answer